# js delete parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem that when I try to delete the li that I made in js, the following code will delete all the list not just the clicked li
and when choosing the parent the span does not work properly

```
function showdata() {
    var newtodo = $("#newtodo").val();
    $("ol").append('<li class"batodo" >' + newtodo + '<span   class="deltodo">' +" x" + "</span>" + "</li>");
}

$(".deltodo").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".batodo").remove();
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing your elements are organized in a tree structure and the root is being deleted. If so, you should replace `parents(".batodo")` with `closest(".batodo")`. Can you confirm or show us some html example?

Comment: @Satpal Although OP is incorrectly using event binding, his question title and description suggest a totally different problem. I don't see this as a duplicate, or at least not of `Event binding on dynamically created elements`

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin reopened

Comment: have you tried to console.log($(this)) to make sure that it's targeting the right element. It should but you never know.

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle or a working code?

Comment: https://github.com/had-e/egydo newtodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

the working code thanks for helping :)

```
function showdata() {
var newtodo = $("#newtodo").val();
$("ol").append('<li class"batodo" >' + newtodo + '<span class="deltodo">' +" del" + '</span>' + "</li>");
$(".deltodo").click(function(){
        $(this).parents("li:first").remove();
    });
```

};